# How to Cast a Quadratic Constraint as Convex if Q is a (PSD) Variable?

Tags: convex-optimization, matrix-decomposition, positive-semidefinite, quadratic-programming, second-order-cone-programming

### Background

I am working on a stochastic optimal control problem and $x$ represents the state of the dynamic system. The optimal state must be found, but, due to the stochastic nature of the problem, the state variables are random variables. So, I am assuming that they can be approximated by a multivariate normal distribution $x \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, P)$ and using the first two moments of the distribution (mean $\mu$ and covariance $P$) to set up a deterministic optimization problem.

### System Dynamics

The state is subject to linear time-varying stochastic dynamics
$$ dx = (A(t) x + B(t) u) dt + G dw $$
where $u$ is the control (another optimization variable) and $w$ is a Wiener process with diffusion coefficient $G$.
The control is assumed to be composed of a feedforward signal $\nu(t)$ and a state feedback that compensates deviations from the mean.
$$ u = \nu + K (x - \mu) $$
Both $\nu$ and $K$ must be optimized.

Rather than considering the stochastic differential equation, one can deal with the ODEs for the mean and the covariance of state
\begin{align}
\dot{\mu} &= A x + B \nu \\
\dot{P} &= (A + BK) P + P (A + BK)^T + G G^T
\end{align}
By introducing a change of variables $Z = K P$ and optimizing $Z$ instead of $K$, the second ODE is linear in $P$ and $Z$
$$ \dot{P} = A P + P A^T + B Z + Z^T B^T + G G^T $$

Finally, the differential constraints are converted into algebraic constraints via a collocation method (e.g., trapezoidal).

### Chance Constraints

The problem features some linear chance constraints that look like
$$ \text{Pr}\left\{ c^T x \leq d \right\} \geq p $$
where $x$ is a vector of $n$ (random) variables to optimize, $c$ is a given coefficient vector of length $n$, $d$ is a given scalar, and $p$ represents the desired probability.

Rather than considering $c^T x$, it is convenient to define a random variable with a standard normal distribution $y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.
Indeed, according to the central limit theorem, the sum of multiple random variables tends to a normal distribution.
Such a variable can be related to $c^T x$ by subtracting the mean and normalizing with respect to the covariance
\begin{equation}
    y = \frac{c^T x - c^T \mu}{\sqrt{c^T P c}}
\end{equation}
So, the chance constraint can be expressed as
\begin{equation}
    \text{Pr}\{c^T x \leq d\} = \text{Pr}\left\{y \leq \frac{d - c^T \mu}{\sqrt{c^T P c}}\right\} = \Phi\left(\frac{d - c^T \mu}{\sqrt{c^T P c}}\right) \geq p
\end{equation}
where $\Phi$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution.
By considering the left-side $p$-quantile, denoted $z_p$, of the standard normal distribution, the constraint becomes
\begin{equation}
    \frac{d - c^T \mu}{\sqrt{c^T P c}} \geq z_p
\end{equation}

### Chance Constraint as a (Convex?) Quadratic Constraint

So, I converted the probabilistic constraint into a deterministic one by replacing $x$ by its mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $P$ and obtained
$$ z_p \sqrt{c^T P c} + c^T \mu - d \leq 0 $$

The above constraint is supposed to be convex since $z_p > 0$ and the covariance matrix $P$ is positive semi-definite (PSD). However, $P$ is an optimization variable and I am having some trouble casting the constraint as a convex quadratic constraint or second-order cone in Gurobi. Gurobi accepts only the three following families of convex quadratic constraints:

1. $x^T Q x + q x \leq b$ where $Q$ is PSD (Convex quadratic constraint)
2. $ x^T x \leq y^2 $ where $y \geq 0$ (Second-order cone constraint)
3. $ x^T x \leq y z $ where $y \geq 0$ and $z \geq 0$ (Rotated second-order cone constraint)

I have tried to introduce an auxiliary variable $s \geq 0$ as
$$z_p \sqrt{c^T P c} \leq s \leq - c^T \mu + d$$
and then replace the constraint by the following pair of constraints
$$-c^T \mu + d = s $$
$$z_p^2 c^T P c \leq s^2 $$
but the second one belongs to family 1 since the left-hand side is linear in P and is a nonconvex constraint because $s^2$ is on the right side of the equation, thus $Q = - I$.

A standard approach would be decomposing the PSD covariance matrix as $P = R^T R$ and then obtain
$$ z_p || R c || \leq - c^T \mu + d $$
which is a second-order constraint, but I don't know how to obtain an expression for $R$ since the elements of $P$ are optimization variables and, even after introducing $R$ as additional variables, then a constraint as $P = R^T R$ would be nonconvex.

So, how should I cast the quadratic constraint and still retain a convex formulation if my optimization variables are the vector $\mu$ and the PSD matrix $P$?

Comment: What a peculiar situation where you can optimize the mean and covariance matrix. Could you elaborate on the background?

Comment: Use the constraint with $R$ and remove $P$ from the optimization problem. Does $P$ appear elsewhere?

Comment: @LinAlg Yes, $P$ appears in other constraints of the problem. Indeed, I need to propagate the covariance from an initial time $t_0$ to a final time $t_f$ via the Riccati differential equation $\dot{P} = A P + P A^T$, and then impose the chance constraint on $P(t_f)$.

Comment: I would also like to see the rest of the optimization problem, because the problem cannot be studied in isolation (like the formulation with $R$ shows).

Comment: @LinAlg I added the rest of the optimization problem, which consists of differential constraints. The ODEs are then transcribed as algebraic constraints via collocation.